# Error with mysql request and reserved word as column name

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql table i have column named with reserved word "from", so i tried request with backtips like this

```
SELECT * FROM timesheets  WHERE user_id = 1 WHERE `from` <= 2013-10-31 WHERE `from` > 2013-01-01
```

but it doesn't work, there is an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: You have two `where` clauses. The second 'where' should be 'OR' to be logically correct.

Comment: probably `AND`, not `Or`, but otherwise, spot-on... you should make that an answer, @comfreek.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, I actually had 'AND' in my initial revision of that comment. Writing an answer now.

Comment: The dates also need to be quoted, otherwise it's going to be treated as subtraction: `2013-10-31` -> `1972`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have three `WHERE` clauses in your SQL statement.

  ```
  WHERE user_id = 1 WHERE `from` <= 2013-10-31 WHERE `from` > 2013-01-01
  ```
- You didn't quote your dates.

These points make your SQL query invalid.

→ Replace your superfluos `WHERE` clauses by `AND`s:

```
WHERE user_id = 1 AND (`from` <= '2013-10-31' AND `from` > '2013-01-01')
```

→ You can even use `BETWEEN ... AND ...` for Dates:

```
WHERE user_id = 1 AND (`from` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-31')
```

The parentheses should not be necessary, but I prefer adding them for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid SQL. You can only have one WHERE clause in a query, and you have 3.
As far as the "reserved" column name, you should be ok as long as you put the backticks (`from`).

You may be looking for something like this:

```
select *
from timesheets
where user_id = 1
AND `from` BETWEEN  '2013 - 01 - 01' AND '2013 - 10 - 31';
```